# Django modify queryset values before rendering on the template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have a `FormView` that sends data to a `ListView`.
In the `LisView` I get the data with `self.request.GET` and unsing a qustom filter I get the queryset that I need. 
Now I need to modify some values in the queryset, but I dont find how.

Tried indexing the queriset in the `ListView` with `queriset['name']`, or `queryset[1]`, but its tell me that the index is not suported.
Tried apply `queryset.values_list()` and `queriset.values()` then indexing, but the same result apears.
Tried to create a function in the `ListView` and apply in the template getting 'Could not parse the reminder'.
Finally tried to rest the values in the template by doing object.value - request.GET.value but I get this error:
`Could not parse the remainder: ' - request.GET.salary' from 'item.smg70 - request.GET.salary'`

**views.py**

```
class QuoteListView(ListView):
    model = SmgQuotesTable

    def get_queryset(self):
        r_get = self.request.GET
        d_get = {'name': None , 'email':None , 'couple': None, 'age': None, 'kids':None , 'salary':None}

        for value in d_get:
            d_get[value] = r_get[value]

        query_filter = Quotes().planSelector(d_get['couple'], d_get['kids'], d_get['age'])
        queryset = super(QuoteListView, self).get_queryset().filter(composite=query_filter)

        for i in queryset[1:]:
            i - d_get['salary']
            print(i)


        return queryset


    def salary(self, x):
        salary_get = self.request.GET('salary')

        return x - salary_get
```

**smgquotestable_list.html**

```
{% for item in object_list %}
<div class="table-responsive text-nowrap"></div>
  <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col"></th>
          <th scope="col">SMG01</th>
          <th scope="col">SMG02</th>
          <th scope="col">SMG10</th>
          <th scope="col">SMG20</th>
          <th scope="col">SMG30</th>
          <th scope="col">SMG40</th>
          <th scope="col">SMG50</th>
          <th scope="col">SMG60</th>
          <th scope="col">SMG70</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{ item.composite }}</th>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg01 }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg02 }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg10 }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg20 }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg30 }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg40 }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg50 }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg60 }}</td>
          <td>$ {{ item.smg70 }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I need to rest the salary value send by the form to the values of smg01 etc that I get in the queryset.

Comment: what error are you getting? show us full trace. Also what is `Quote()` and what is `planSelector()` method? No idea what `filter(composite=query_filter)` is supposed to do, what is `composite`?

Comment: A queryset returns a set of objects, which you can iterate. So if you want to modify the objects, you have to loop through the set/list (`for object in queryset:`) and then change each object.

Comment: `Quotes` is a custom class and `planSelector` is method i made for filter the model with the information sendit by the form and get the _queryset_ i need.
`Composite` is the name of the column on the model where i apply the filter. 

When I try to iteraty the queryset I only get the value of the 'composite' column, not the others atributes of the model.

Comment: When you iterate, `object` is an instance of the `SmgQuotesTable` model. So you can access all fields of the model. Unless there’s code you’re not showing us on the queryset (E.g. values or values_list). Add the code where you iterate.

Comment: I use this yust above the queryset in the listview:  
`for i in queryset:            print(i)`  
I only can acces to the others values in the template. Could that be because in the tempalte use the filter queryset to get the info?

Comment: No a `filter` just limits which objects are in the set. Please add the code to your question, where you iterate and change the values. I can't help if you don't show us the code that is failing.

Comment: Done. I put the code extra I'm triaing in the `get_queryset`

Comment: I told you: iterating through the queryset gives you instances of `SmgQuotesTable` so you can't do `i - ...` because `i` is a `SmgQuotesTable` object. You should do `for quote in queryset: salary = quote.smg01 - d_get['salary']` or something similar (I don't know how your `SmgQuotesTable` looks like).

Comment: Niceee dirkgrote!!!  You are right!
Thanks, now I understunt and can edited on the fly!   
I gonna pull it and then post who i did it.  
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was in not understanding as dirkgroten told me, that it was an instance of the object.
So I needed to use `i.value` to use access the value.

Here is how I solved it:

In `quotes.py` I write the function called `salaryDiscount` that modifies the values on the run:

```
    def salaryDiscount(self, queryset, salary):
        '''
        This function apply the salary discount to all the values for this person. 
        '''
        salary = float(salary) * 0.03  # Take the salary, and aply the part that could be discounted

        for i in queryset:  # Get the object of the queryset
            i.smg01 = round(i.smg01  - salary, 2)    # Use the object edit the values on the fly
            i.smg02 = round(i.smg02  - salary, 2)
            i.smg10 = round(i.smg10  - salary, 2)
            i.smg20 = round(i.smg20  - salary, 2)
            i.smg30 = round(i.smg30  - salary, 2)
            i.smg40 = round(i.smg40  - salary, 2)
            i.smg50 = round(i.smg50  - salary, 2)
            i.smg60 = round(i.smg60  - salary, 2)
            i.smg70 = round(i.smg70  - salary, 2)

        return queryset   # Return the queryset edited.
```

Then I call it on the `get_queryset` of the `ListView` where modify the queryset:

```
class QuoteListView(ListView):
    model = SmgQuotesTable

    def get_queryset(self):
        r_get = self.request.GET   # Get the data sendir by QuoteFormView
        query_filter = Quotes().planSelector(r_get['couple'], r_get['kids'], r_get['age']) # Use the filter to get the correct Quote
        queryset = super(QuoteListView, self).get_queryset().filter(composite=query_filter) # Aply the filter to get the correct queryset
        Quotes().salaryDiscount(queryset,r_get['salary'])  # Aply the discount of the salary

        return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use update on queryset or iterate as dirkgroten mentioned

Comment: this is not really an answer, rather a comment. Please use comments if you're trying to guide towards an answer.

Comment: My rank is too low for comment!

Comment: Then have patience :-) give some good answers and you'll quickly get enough points to comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sharing a few things like the model fields for your SmgQuotesTable or your code for Quote and planSelector.  But, assuming that you are trying to filter the result using the values you get in your self.request object (e.g. values for name, email, couple, etc.) and assuming that these are in fact the fields for your SmgQuotesTable, you should go about this the conventional way (see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering)).  Also, note that you do not need to call Super in get_queryset.  You may be confusing that with get_context_data

which you would need to call super to get the context.

```
class QuoteListView(ListView):
    model = SmgQuotesTable

    def get_queryset(self):
        r_get = self.request.GET
        d_get = {'name': None , 'email':None , 'couple': None, 'age': None, 'kids':None , 'salary':None}

        for value in d_get:
            d_get[value] = r_get[value]  # I do NOT know what you are doing here, so I am going by your code

        filtered_quotes = SmgQuotesTable.objects.filter(**d_get)

        return filtered_quotes
```

Comment: the OP asked how to change queryset values before rendering to the template, he didn't say the queryset filter wasn't working.

Comment: You are correct!  I just saw the unusual code for get_queryset, hence the answer.  It would have been better to mention that in the comments, but the code could be better shown in an answer.  As for modifying the queryset, it may be best to do that in the template as you do not want to save over the instances in the database by changing the value of each instance and saving them.  The other option is to create a different kind of variable and storing the relevant data in there using values_list().